# Excel to Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, excel

Need help to translate excel formula to MySQL query

here is the question =(SUM(D2:D5189))/(SUM(C2:C5189)).

Thanks much for in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKAj6.png)

Comment: Please add sql table definitions, sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: How is that dynamic?

Comment: My problem is this =(SUM(D2:D5189))/(SUM(C2:C5189)). is dynamic for example =(SUM(D2:D5189))/(SUM(C2:C5189)), =(SUM(D3:D5189))/(SUM(C3:C5189)) and =(SUM(D4:D5189))/(SUM(C4:C5189)) to get the specific value per row

Comment: Forget translation and state the question in terms of the data stored in sql..

Comment: Hello I attached on the screenshot above please see. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you cut this down to a manageable representative - size say 5 rows..

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(dt date,cola int,colb int);
insert into t values
(str_to_date('29/10/2020','%d/%m/%Y'),147,150),
(str_to_date('30/10/2020','%d/%m/%Y'),160,170),
(str_to_date('01/11/2020','%d/%m/%Y'),170,170),
(str_to_date('02/11/2020','%d/%m/%Y'),180,170),
(str_to_date('03/11/2020','%d/%m/%Y'),190,170);
```

You could use correlated sub queries to get the totals from the current row to the end of column

```
select t.*,
         (select sum(cola) from t t1 where t1.dt >=t.dt) sumcola,
         (select sum(colb) from t t1 where t1.dt >=t.dt) sumcolb,
         (select sum(colb) from t t1 where t1.dt >=t.dt) /
         (select sum(cola) from t t1 where t1.dt >=t.dt) kpi
from t;
```

Or if you have version 8 or above

```
select t.*,
         sum(cola) over (order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) sumcola,
         sum(colb) over (order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) sumcolb,
         sum(colb) over (order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) /
         sum(cola) over (order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) kpi;
from t;

+------------+------+------+---------+---------+--------+
| dt         | cola | colb | sumcola | sumcolb | kpi    |
+------------+------+------+---------+---------+--------+
| 2020-10-29 |  147 |  150 |     847 |     830 | 0.9799 |
| 2020-10-30 |  160 |  170 |     700 |     680 | 0.9714 |
| 2020-11-01 |  170 |  170 |     540 |     510 | 0.9444 |
| 2020-11-02 |  180 |  170 |     370 |     340 | 0.9189 |
| 2020-11-03 |  190 |  170 |     190 |     170 | 0.8947 |
+------------+------+------+---------+---------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solve my problem hehehe

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
 " =INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col1`,`col2`)  VALUES ('"&Q2&"','"&R2&"');"
```